# Why would a gas fireplace have tiny flame and fog up the glass?

Tags: fireplace

I just bought a condo and I hate the gas fireplace!  I can barely see the flame or the wood against the black background. The flame is tiny, only 3 to 4" and doesn't extend above the wood.

Another concern is when the glass is over the opening, it starts fogging up right away.  Does this mean that it is not properly vented?  I specifically looked for a home with a fireplace and have owned several gas units before but nothing as pitiful as this!  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest having a fireplace person come on out and take a look. Sounds like you're getting a bad burn with excess moisture. It could be due to a variety of things:

- air intake (or exhaust) is plugged. Birds in the chimney?
- problem with fuel intake (leak? Kink in the line?)
- dirty burner element